# Adding "cacheControlMaxAge" parameter into sddraft

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-server, python-2.7, xml

I would like adding a new parameter into my sddraft, the value of "cacheControlMaxAge".
For this, I have the following code that modifies the value of already existing parameters :

```py
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
doc = dom.parse(r"Z:\secret_folder\service.sddraft")
configProps = doc.getElementsByTagName('ConfigurationProperties')[0]
configPropArray = configProps.firstChild
configPropSets = configPropArray.childNodes
for configPropSet in configPropSets:
    configPropKeyValues = configPropSet.childNodes
    for configPropKeyValue in configPropKeyValues:
        if configPropKeyValue.tagName == 'Key':
            if configPropKeyValue.firstChild.data == 'cacheControlMaxAge':
                configPropKeyValue.nextSibling.firstChild.data = 604800
                print "OK"
            else:
                print "KO"
```

However, it seems that the parameter does not exist :

```py
KO
```

If I am wrong with variable name/parameter, how do I add this parameter in the sddraft ?

Comment: How do you create the `sddraft`, how are you planning to use it, and why do you need this extra parameter?

Comment: I created the sddraft file with the python function `arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft`.

Comment: I planned to use it in order to generate a sd file using the python function `arcpy.StageService_server`.

Comment: I need this parameter to increase the caching time of query responses for a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to the problem described above. There it is :

```py
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

doc = dom.parse(r"Z:\secret_folder\service.sddraft")

PropertySetProperty_balise = doc.createElement("PropertySetProperty")  # creation d une balise PropertySetProperty
PropertySetProperty_balise.setAttribute("xsi:type", "typens:PropertySetProperty")  # ajout de l attribut xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty" a la balise PropertySetProperty
key_balise = doc.createElement("Key")  # creation d une balise Key
key_value = doc.createTextNode("cacheControlMaxAge")  # creation d un texte de valeur "cacheControlMaxAge"
key_balise.appendChild(key_value)  # insertion de la balise texte de valeur "cacheControlMaxAge" dans la balise Key
value_balise = doc.createElement("Value")  # creation d une balise Value
value_balise.setAttribute("xsi:type", "xs:double")  # parametrage du type de la balise Value
value_value = doc.createTextNode(cacheControlMaxAge)  # creation d un texte de valeur numerique cacheControlMaxAge
value_balise.appendChild(604800)  # insertion de la balise texte de valeur numerique cacheControlMaxAge dans la balise Value
PropertySetProperty_balise.appendChild(key_balise)  # insertion de la balise Key dans la balise PropertySetProperty
PropertySetProperty_balise.appendChild(value_balise)  # insertion de la balise Value dans la balise PropertySetProperty

configProps = doc.getElementsByTagName('ConfigurationProperties')[0]
configPropArray = configProps.firstChild
configPropArray.appendChild(PropertySetProperty_balise)  # insertion de la balise PropertySetProperty dans la balise PropertyArray
configPropSets = configPropArray.childNodes
for configPropSet in configPropSets:
    configPropKeyValues = configPropSet.childNodes
    for configPropKeyValue in configPropKeyValues:
        if configPropKeyValue.tagName == 'Key':
            if configPropKeyValue.firstChild.data == 'cacheControlMaxAge':
                print configPropKeyValue.nextSibling.firstChild.data
            else:
                print "KO"
```

And I get :

```
604800
```

In fact I manually created all the necessary tags, without forgetting to configure their type (to keep a valid sddraft) then I inserted the tags in the right place.

Thanks for your intervention,

Hope this will help you.